# Layout Design Preview are not showing in Android Studio for AOSP Development. How to enable design preview?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-source

I've imported AOSP into Android Studio by andorid.ipr file generated by IDEGEN.
But the design preview is not showing. How to configure Android Studio for Building and showing Layout Previews?

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Comment: Is anybody able to do this?? Not even clear if it will be possible with android studio for Platform brand new IDE.. so frustrating.. anybody has a walkthrough to show how to export an app with deps from aosp to android studio?  So frustrating